# Como transformar uma div com 4 imagens em apenas uma?

Tags: php, jquery, html5, processamento-de-imagens

Eu tenho um código HTML assim:

```
<div class="conteudoFrente">
    <div id="draggable">
        <div class="draggableFrase">

        </div>                   
    </div>
</div>
```

A div com a classe *"conteudoFrente"* tem uma imagem de fundo.

A div com id *"draggable"* ela pode receber até 4 imagens que o usuário envia por um formulário com 4 inputs file, e ela possui o *"width:150px; height:194px"* (um retângulo de pé).

A div com a classe *"draggableFrase"* recebe uma frase digitada pelo usuário, o mesmo formulário agora com um campo input text

OBS: eu estou usando a biblioteca *jQuery UI* (componentes: *Draggable e Resizable)*. Então, quando o usuário envia a primeira imagem, ele pode arrastá-la para qualquer lugar do retângulo, e, também pode redimensioná-la. As demais imagens do mesmo jeito, podendo até colocar uma por cima da outra, porém mais a direita, deixando apenas metade de uma imagem amostra.
Do mesmo modo, a frase digitada por ele também pode ser arrastada por qualquer lugar do retângulo.

***A dúvida:***

Eu consigo recuperar todas as imagens e a frase e salvá-los no banco de dados, **porém eu não consigo saber a posição das imagens, se elas foram redimensionadas ou não, se a frase digitada está em cima, no meio ou embaixo.**

***Sugestão:***

Tentar de alguma forma, transformar a div "conteudoFrente" em apenas uma imagem, ou pdf, ou até transformar toda a página HTML em uma url, não sei.

Eu só preciso conseguir recuperar as informações do mesmo jeito que o usuário as definiu.

Espero ter explicado direito, porém estou a disposição para responder a alguma dúvida que tenha deixado no ar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme a documentação do [Evento **stop** do Resizable Widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#event-stop) e do [Evento **stop** do Draggable Widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-stop) você tem acesso a duas propriedades:

- `position` (draggable | resizable)
- `size` (resizable)

Que são respectivamente a posição e as dimensões do elemento que foi redimensionado e movido.

De posse desses dados, você pode criar (via JavaScript, pelo JQuery mesmo ou na mão) campos (*input*) do tipo oculto (*type="hidden"*) e alocar as informações que você precisa lá e depois no PHP recuperar esses campos, da mesma forma que você faz com a frase e com as imagens...

Faça um teste:

```
$(".draggableFrase") /*Obtemos o elemento que armazena a frase */
.draggable() /* Ativamos a função de mover no elemento */
.resizable({ /* Ativamos a função de redimenciona no elemento */
    stop: function( event, ui ) { /* Adicionamos uma ação para o evento 'stop' */
       console.log(ui.position); /* Exibe no console a posição (left & top) */
       console.log(ui.size); /* Exibe no console as dimensões (width & height) */
    }
});
```

Abra o console do seu navegador (se for o Google Chrome, presisone a tecla **F12** ou as teclas **CTRL** + **SHIFT** + **I**) e veja o que aparece na aba **Console** conforme você movimenta e redimensiona a *frase*

Answer (score 1):

> [...] transformar a div "conteudoFrente" em apenas uma imagem, ou pdf,
>   ou até transformar toda a página HTML em uma url[...]

Você pode utilizar a biblioteca [Html2Canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) para converter sua página, ou parte dela, para um `DataURL` - e submeter o resultado para seu servidor.

Para fins de teste, utilize o seguinte snippet:

```
var minhaImagem = minhaDiv.toDataURL("image/png");
window.open(myImage);
```